# Idiomatic/Proper Go code refactoring for a UnionFind library

Tags: go

I am practicing a classic algorithm problem in go "number of islands". I want to solve it using unionfind. Although I can tweak and make it work, I would like to know the best way to structure my code.

Here is the main program.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"

  u "practice/leetcode/library/unionfind"
)

type point u.Point

func numIslands(grid [][]byte) int {
  res := 0
  if grid == nil || grid[0] == nil {
    return res
  }
  m := len(grid)
  n := len(grid[0])
  num := 0
  uf := u.NewUnionFind()
  directions := []point{
    point{1, 0}, 
    point{-1, 0},
    point{0, 1},
    point{0, -1},
  }
  emptyPoint := point{}
  for i := 0; i < m; i++ {
    for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
      if grid[i][j] == 1 {
        p := point{i, j}
        uf.Add(p)
        num++
        for _, v := range directions {
          newx := i + v.X 
          newy := j + v.Y
          if 0 <= newx && newx < m && 0 <= newy && newy < n && grid[newx][newy] == 1 {
            newp := point{newx, newy}
            if uf.Find(newp) == emptyPoint {
              continue
            }
            uf.Union(p, newp)
            num--
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return num
}

func main() {
  // expect 1
  grid := [][]byte {
    {1,1,1,1,0},
    {1,1,0,1,0},
    {1,1,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0},
  }
  fmt.Println(numIslands(grid))
  
  // expect 2
  grid = [][]byte {
    {1,0},
    {0,1},
  }
  fmt.Println(numIslands(grid))
}
```

Here is the unionfind library I wrote

```
package unionfind

type Point struct {
  X int
  Y int
}

type UnionFind struct {
  parent map[Point]Point
}

func NewUnionFind() *UnionFind {
  parent := make(map[Point]Point)
  return &UnionFind{parent}
}

func (uf *UnionFind) Add(c Point) {
  if _, ok := uf.parent[c]; ok {
    return
  }
  uf.parent[c] = c
}

func (uf *UnionFind) Find(c Point) Point {
  if p, ok := uf.parent[c]; ok {
    if p != c {
      uf.parent[c] = uf.Find(p)
    }
    return uf.parent[c]
  }
  return Point{}
}

func (uf *UnionFind) Union(c1 Point, c2 Point) {
  p1 := uf.Find(c1)
  p2 := uf.Find(c2)
  if p1 != p2 {
    uf.parent[p1] = p2
  }
}
```

The problem is when I ran the main program, i got the following errors:

```
# command-line-arguments
./200_number_of_islands_uf.go:31:15: cannot use p (type point) as type unionfind.Point in argument to uf.Add
./200_number_of_islands_uf.go:38:23: cannot use newp (type point) as type unionfind.Point in argument to uf.Find
./200_number_of_islands_uf.go:38:30: invalid operation: uf.Find(newp) == emptyPoint (mismatched types unionfind.Point and point)
./200_number_of_islands_uf.go:41:21: cannot use p (type point) as type unionfind.Point in argument to uf.Union
./200_number_of_islands_uf.go:41:21: cannot use newp (type point) as type unionfind.Point in argument to uf.Union
```

The hard requirement I want is:
1.I want to keep the unionfind as a library
2.I need to access the Point struct in the main program

The design requirement I am trying to follow is:
I tried to avoid using an interface for the UnionFind parent map since I can foresee only the Point struct get pass in to the library.

My requirements could be wrong. I am open to suggestions to refactor the code and make it more elegant looking.

Comment: Just delete `type point u.Point` and use the `u.Point` type directly.

Comment: @Crowman Thank you! Do you like to write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
type point u.Point
```

then `point` is not just an aliased name for `u.Point` which can be used interchangeably - it's an entirely new type, and one which your `uniontype` package knows nothing about and therefore will not accept.

So just don't do that, and instead directly use the type the `uniontype` package provides for you. For example, change:

```
directions := []point{
    point{1, 0}, 
    point{-1, 0},
    point{0, 1},
    point{0, -1},
}
emptyPoint := point{}
```

to:

```
directions := []u.Point{
    u.Point{1, 0}, 
    u.Point{-1, 0},
    u.Point{0, 1},
    u.Point{0, -1},
}
emptyPoint := u.Point{}
```

and so on.